# Ensuring correct date/time

Tags: iphone, android

we are creating a location-enabled app where users use this app to record certain events in the field.

The important part of the event data is when an event happened. This is no issue when user is online, but we also support situations when user is offline (by remembering & later syncing events).

There could be situations when users are offline and they change the time on the phone, so that event times are wrongly recorded.

So, what would be the best way to ensure we get a correct time, independent of user actions,  given that device could be offline. Some ideas:

1. GPS time. Is it possible to acquire it?
2. Tracking system time changes made by user?
3. Any other idea?

Note: time does need second accuracy, approximately minute accuracy would be ok.

Note2: we are creating mobile apps for Android and iPhone, so I'm interested for generic solutions and also solutions that are specific to any of those two platforms.

Comment: I think GSM networks are able to provide the current time and many do. So if the handset is on a network, it should sync with that time.

Comment: This is a non-issue when device is online - we can check time on our server when events are sent. The issue only arises when device is offline.

Comment: Peter - sorry to abuse this SO comment, but I can find no other way to reach you.  I cannot post a comment to your blog entry concerning the analysis of SO user data.  Post and preview both simply reload the page.  Cookies are on for blogspot, I have a google.com account.  I guess cookies are required also for some additional third domains, but there's no way to know.

Comment is here; http://slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=2328930&cid=36789036

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, personally, wouldn't worry so much about this scenario. The liklihood of someone intentionally changing the time on their Android (which periodically throughout the day syncs to a time server automatically) while offline seems low to me. That being said, the only way I could see compensating for this is to keep a service running in the background that keeps a running tally of the seconds passed since recording the location data offline. Once uploaded to your servers you could use the elapsed seconds to calculate a time offset from current UTC time. It's an awful lot to go through, but it would work.

GPS time is an interesting idea, but Android allows users of the SDK to send mock locations to their devices. I'm not sure you could reliably track changes to system time either, and even if you could you'd be capturing them after the fact without the current real time as context.

Comment: Well, companies that use this app require their employees to use it when in the field - start work, stop work, etc.. So there is some incentive from employees to tweak it. Especially if a loophole is found.

Comment: Good point about creating mock GPS locations. Will check if this can be detected.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how fraud might be extremely sensitive in a situation like that. Consider then that in my scenario it is still possible to kill background services. I'm not sure if you can minimize the impact of that by periodically persisting that offset data to device storage and restarting the service automatically. Sounds like there's much to consider!

Comment: My idea was similar to yours: record times in the background to check for any "gaps". But instead of background process, which can be killed, I'd use AlarmManager to periodically wake my background service.

Comment: Perhaps then the problem isn't one of recording absolute elapsed time, but discovering inconsistencies? Perhaps a particular task can be invalidated if, by your application logic, you discover attempts to fabricate the elapsed time for a job?

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I was too focused on finding the solution for getting the correct time. Instead, if inconsistencies in time are detected, then those events should just be appropriately flagged in the system, so that people responsible know something is going on.

Answer (score 1):

We use GPS times in our app for very similar reasons. Since our users are in different time zones and we want local times, we define from our server what time zone they are in at installation time (they don't move very far). Hadn't thought of the mock GPS locations, but you would need to be a fairly advanced user to do that.